# ElasticSearch make a field behave like set instead of list

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field in elastic search which has a list of elements, I want to make sure that this list does not have duplicate elements, I have made application side changes, is there a way I can run ES command to update the already indexed documents.

Comment: you want to remove duplicates from the _source or from the indexed tokens? If it is from the token you need to use the unique token filter ( https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-unique-tokenfilter.html ). If you want to remove from the source you will have to go through a pipeline / update_by_query with a script processors casting your List to a Set

Comment: I would need an update by query probably.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is a bit late, but this can be done in two ways:

Let's say that I have the below document:

```
POST sourceindex/mydocs/1
{
  "myIntegerArray": [1,2,3,4,5,5,6],
  "myStringArray" : [ "Chelsea", "Manu", "Arsenal", "Arsenal"]
}
```

### Using script via update by query

```
POST sourceindex/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "source": """
      int size = ctx._source['myIntegerArray'].size();
      int i=0;
      Set myset = new HashSet();
      for(ListIterator it = ctx._source['myIntegerArray'].listIterator(); it.hasNext();){
          i = it.next();
          it.remove();
          myset.add(i);
      }
      ctx._source['myIntegerArray'].addAll(myset);
      """
  }
}
```

### Using Ingest/Pipeline/Processor technique

Here you would need to perform reindex, unlike the update query this would require you to reindex from `sourceindex -> destinationindex`and you may have to reindex again from `destinationindex` to `sourceindex` if the index you intend to use is `sourceindex` and if you are not using any aliasing feature. I'd suggest you to take a look into the [Ingest](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) feature

Breaking down the steps:

```
Create ingestion pipeline
Create dest_index
Apply reindex operation using pipeline to ingest from source_index to dest_index
```

### Sample Pipeline

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/my-pipeline
{
  "description" : "duplicate removal pipeline",
  "processors" : [
    {

        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": """
            int size = ctx.myIntegerArray.size();
            int i=0;
            Set myset = new HashSet();
            for(ListIterator it = ctx.myIntegerArray.listIterator(); it.hasNext();)
            {
              i = it.next();
              it.remove();
              myset.add(i);

            }
            ctx.myIntegerArray.addAll(myset);
            """
        }
   }]
}
```

### Reindexing Query

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "sourceindex"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "destinationindex",
    "pipeline": "my-pipeline"
  }
}
```

Note that I have created this pipeline to remove the duplicate integers. You can make use of `String` in a similar way. Only changes you need to do is, change the line `int i=0` to `String i = null;` (sorry about coding standards here) and change `myIntegerArray` to `myStringArray`

I hope it helps!